# How can I center a tikzpicture without centering the \item that contains it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, horizontal-alignment

I have a particular exercise where I want a diagram I created with `tikzpicture` to be centered, but I also want the label for the `\item` that contains it to be left alone and remain in line with the other enumerators at its level.  I've been successful in finding solutions for the myriad other issues I've had (this is my first LaTeX document), but no matter what answer I've tried, the `\item` label (in this case, a (b)) seems to get pulled along for the ride, like this:

[image: ![center tag itemnapping]

Here's a few examples of what I've tried:

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  ....
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

{\centering

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  ....
  \end{tikzpicture}

}

\begin{figure}
   \begin{center}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
      ....
     \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \centering

  ....
\end{tikzpicture}
```

...et cetera.  I get the "best" results with the first two, which appear identical to me.  The (b) gets pulled over to the center, and there isn't proper vertical spacing between the `tikzpicture` and the text below it.  However, subsequent diagrams (which are all under the same `\item` as the first) don't have this spacing problem.  It seems bizarre to me that `\begin{center}` would pull in something that ought to be outside of its scope, but I'm sure there's a simple explanation.  Here's a minimal(ish) working example (I intend to refactor it to minimize the repetition):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,bm,enumitem,tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes}

\tikzset{
    between/.style args={#1 and #2}{
         at = ($(#1)!0.5!(#2)$)
    }
}

\tikzstyle{mydot}=[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt]
\tikzstyle{myellipse}=[ellipse,draw=cyan,thick,minimum width=60pt,minimum height=110pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{every edge}=[draw=cyan,thick]
\tikzstyle{relarrow}=[->, shorten >= 0pt, shorten <= 0pt, out=25, in=155]

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $R=\{(5,5),(6,5),(6,6)\}$,\\
              $S=\{(4,6),(5,5),(5,7),(6,6)\}$

        \item % Relation R
             \begin{center}
             \begin{tikzpicture}[
             >=latex,
             shorten >= 3pt,
             shorten <= 3pt,
             baseline={([yshift=-1em] current bounding box.north)}
             ]

             \node[mydot,label={left:4}] (a1) {}; 
             \node[mydot,below=of a1,label={left:5}] (a2) {}; 
             \node[mydot,below=of a2,label={left:6}] (a3) {}; 

             \node[mydot,right=5cm of a1,label={right:5}] (b1) {}; 
             \node[mydot,below=of b1,label={right:6}] (b2) {}; 
             \node[mydot,below=of b2,label={right:7}] (b3) {}; 

             \path[->] (a2) edge (b1);
             \path[->] (a3) edge (b1)
                 edge(b2);

             \node[myellipse,label={above:A}] at (a2.center) (c1) {};
             \node[myellipse,label={above:B}] at (b2.center) (c2) {};

             \node at (2.5, 0.75) (r1) {$R$};
             \path[relarrow] (2.1, 0.4) edge (2.95, 0.35);

             \end{tikzpicture}
             \end{center}

             $R$ is not a function because it fails both 
             properties (1) and (2) of the definition of a function.
             $4\in A$, but there is no $(4,y)\in R$ for any 
             $y\in B$.
             Also, \mbox{$(6,5)\in R$} and $(6,6)\in R\text{, but }
             5\neq6$.

             % Relation S
             \begin{center}
             \begin{tikzpicture}[
             >=latex,
             shorten >= 3pt,
             shorten <= 3pt,
             baseline={([yshift=-1em] current bounding box.north)}
             ]

             \node[mydot,label={left:4}] (a1) {}; 
             \node[mydot,below=of a1,label={left:5}] (a2) {}; 
             \node[mydot,below=of a2,label={left:6}] (a3) {}; 

             \node[mydot,right=5cm of a1,label={right:5}] (b1) {}; 
             \node[mydot,below=of b1,label={right:6}] (b2) {}; 
             \node[mydot,below=of b2,label={right:7}] (b3) {}; 

             \path[->] (a1) edge (b2);
             \path[->] (a2) edge (b1)
                 edge (b3);
             \path[->] (a3) edge (b2);

             \node[myellipse,label={above:A}] at (a2.center) (c1) {};
             \node[myellipse,label={above:B}] at (b2.center) (c2) {};

             \node at (2.5, 0.75) (r1) {$S$};
             \path[relarrow] (2.1, 0.4) edge (2.95, 0.35);

             \end{tikzpicture}
             \end{center}

             $S$ is not a function because it fails property 
             (2) of the definition of a function.
             $(5,5)\in S\text{ and }(5,7)\in S\text{, but }
             5\neq7$.

    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What happens if you leave an empty line between your `\item` and the `\begin{center}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider such diagrams as math displays, although adding some introductory text would be better.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,bm,enumitem,tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes}

\tikzset{
  between/.style args={#1 and #2}{at = ($(#1)!0.5!(#2)$)},
  mydot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt},
  myellipse/.style={
    ellipse,
    draw=cyan,
    thick,
    minimum width=60pt,
    minimum height=110pt,
    inner sep=0pt
  },
  every edge/.style={draw=cyan,thick},
  relarrow/.style={->, shorten >= 0pt, shorten <= 0pt, out=25, in=155},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item $R=\{(5,5),(6,5),(6,6)\}$,\\
        $S=\{(4,6),(5,5),(5,7),(6,6)\}$

  \item % Relation R
    \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      >=latex,
      shorten >= 3pt,
      shorten <= 3pt,
      baseline={([yshift=-1em] current bounding box.north)}
    ]

    \node[mydot,label={left:4}] (a1) {}; 
    \node[mydot,below=of a1,label={left:5}] (a2) {}; 
    \node[mydot,below=of a2,label={left:6}] (a3) {}; 

    \node[mydot,right=5cm of a1,label={right:5}] (b1) {}; 
    \node[mydot,below=of b1,label={right:6}] (b2) {}; 
    \node[mydot,below=of b2,label={right:7}] (b3) {}; 

    \path[->] (a2) edge (b1);
    \path[->] (a3) edge (b1) edge(b2);

    \node[myellipse,label={above:$A$}] at (a2.center) (c1) {};
    \node[myellipse,label={above:$B$}] at (b2.center) (c2) {};

    \node at (2.5, 0.75) (r1) {$R$};
    \path[relarrow] (2.1, 0.4) edge (2.95, 0.35);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
    $R$ is not a function because it fails both 
    properties (1) and (2) of the definition of a function.
    $4\in A$, but there is no $(4,y)\in R$ for any $y\in B$.
    Also, $(6,5)\in R$ and $(6,6)\in R$, but~$5\neq6$.

  \item % Relation S
    \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      >=latex,
      shorten >= 3pt,
      shorten <= 3pt,
      baseline={([yshift=-1em] current bounding box.north)}
    ]

    \node[mydot,label={left:4}] (a1) {}; 
    \node[mydot,below=of a1,label={left:5}] (a2) {}; 
    \node[mydot,below=of a2,label={left:6}] (a3) {}; 

    \node[mydot,right=5cm of a1,label={right:5}] (b1) {}; 
    \node[mydot,below=of b1,label={right:6}] (b2) {}; 
    \node[mydot,below=of b2,label={right:7}] (b3) {}; 

    \path[->] (a1) edge (b2);
    \path[->] (a2) edge (b1) edge (b3);
    \path[->] (a3) edge (b2);

    \node[myellipse,label={above:$A$}] at (a2.center) (c1) {};
    \node[myellipse,label={above:$B$}] at (b2.center) (c2) {};

    \node at (2.5, 0.75) (r1) {$S$};
    \path[relarrow] (2.1, 0.4) edge (2.95, 0.35);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
    $S$ is not a function because it fails property (2) of
    the definition of a function.
    $(5,5)\in S$ and $(5,7)\in S$, but~$5\neq7$.

  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

A few points to note:

1. `\tikzstyle` is deprecated
2. The set names should be in math mode: `label={above:$A$}` works for this
3. The text

   ```
   Also, \mbox{$(6,5)\in R$} and $(6,6)\in R\text{, but } 5\neq6$.
   ```

   should be

   ```
   Also, $(6,5)\in R$ and $(6,6)\in R$, but~$5\neq6$.
   ```
4. Similarly, the text

   ```
   $(5,5)\in S\text{ and }(5,7)\in S\text{, but } 5\neq7$.
   ```

   should be

   ```
   $(5,5)\in S$ and $(5,7)\in S$, but~$5\neq7$.
   ```
5. Leave no blank line between `\]` and the following text.

[image]

Comment: Well, I'd argue that you may want to put some non-breaking space too... like `but~$5\neq6$.`It would be really ugly to have a line that ends in `but` and only the `$5\neq6$.` on the next line.

Comment: @Bakuriu I thought to add ties, but the main aspect was separating the formulas from text.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add `\mbox{}` or some text to carry the item label

[image]

```
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $R=\{(5,5),(6,5),(6,6)\}$,\\
              $S=\{(4,6),(5,5),(5,7),(6,6)\}$

        \item \mbox{}
             \begin{center}
             \begin{tikzpicture}[
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

[image]

Solution is rather simple. after `\item` for `b` just add `~` or `\mbox{}`. Complete MWE is than (after small changes) is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{enumitem,tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes}

\tikzset{          >=latex,
           shorten >=3pt,
           shorten <=3pt,
between/.style args ={#1 and #2}{at = ($(#1)!0.5!(#2)$)},
      mydot/.style  ={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt},
  myellipse/.style  ={ellipse,draw=cyan,thick,
                      minimum width=60pt,minimum height=110pt,
                      inner sep=0pt},
 every edge/.style  ={draw=cyan,thick},
   relarrow/.style  ={->, out=25, in=155}
        }

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $R=\{(5,5),(6,5),(6,6)\}$,\\
              $S=\{(4,6),(5,5),(5,7),(6,6)\}$

        \item \mbox{}% <-- added      (Relation R  )
             \begin{center}
             \begin{tikzpicture}[
             baseline={([yshift=-1em] current bounding box.north)}
                                ]
             \node[mydot,label={left:4}] (a1) {};
             \node[mydot,below=of a1,label={left:5}] (a2) {};
             \node[mydot,below=of a2,label={left:6}] (a3) {};

             \node[mydot,right=5cm of a1,label={right:5}] (b1) {};
             \node[mydot,below=of b1,label={right:6}] (b2) {};
             \node[mydot,below=of b2,label={right:7}] (b3) {};

             \path[->] (a2) edge (b1);
             \path[->] (a3) edge (b1) edge (b2);

             \node[myellipse,label={above:A}] at (a2.center) (c1) {};
             \node[myellipse,label={above:B}] at (b2.center) (c2) {};

             \node at (2.5, 0.75) (r1) {$R$};
             \path[relarrow] (2.1, 0.4) edge (2.95, 0.35);
             \end{tikzpicture}
             \end{center}

     $R$ is not a function because it fails both properties (1) and (2) of the definition of a function. $4\in A$, but there is no $(4,y)\in R$ for any $y\in B$. Also, $(6,5)\in R$ and $(6,6)\in R$, but $5\neq6$.

             % Relation S
             \begin{center}
             \begin{tikzpicture}[
             baseline={([yshift=-1em] current bounding box.north)}
                                ]
             \node[mydot,label=left:4] (a1) {};
             \node[mydot,below=of a1,label=left:5] (a2) {};
             \node[mydot,below=of a2,label=left:6] (a3) {};

             \node[mydot,right=5cm of a1,label=right:5] (b1) {};
             \node[mydot,below=of b1,label=right:6] (b2) {};
             \node[mydot,below=of b2,label=right:7] (b3) {};

             \path[->] (a1) edge (b2);
             \path[->] (a2) edge (b1)
                 edge (b3);
             \path[->] (a3) edge (b2);

             \node[myellipse,label=above:A] at (a2.center) (c1) {};
             \node[myellipse,label=above:B] at (b2.center) (c2) {};

             \node at (2.5, 0.75) (r1) {$S$};
             \path[relarrow] (2.1, 0.4) edge (2.95, 0.35);
             \end{tikzpicture}
             \end{center}

             $S$ is not a function because it fails property (2) of the definition of a function. $(5,5)\in S$ and $(5,7)\in S$, but $5\neq7$.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```